# Java finding substring

Tags: java, string, substring

I have the following String:

```
oauth_token=safcanhpyuqu96vfhn4w6p9x&**oauth_token_secret=hVhzHVVMHySB**&application_name=Application_Name&login_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi-user.netflix.com%2Foauth%2Flogin%3Foauth_token%3Dsafcanhpyuqu96vfhn4w6p9x
```

I am trying to parse out the value for oauth_token_secret. I need everything from the equals sign (=) to the next ampersand sign (&). So I need to parse out: hVhzHVVMHySB

Currently, I have the following code:

```
Const.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";

Const.tokenSecret = 
  content.substring(content.indexOf((Const.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET + "="))
    + (Const.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET + "=").length(), 
      content.length());
```

This will start at the beginning of the oauth_token_string, but it will not stop at the next ampersand. I am unsure how to specify to stop at the end of the following ampersand. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `indexOf()` methods allow you to specify an optional `fromIndex`. This allows you to find the next ampersand:

```
int oauth = content.indexOf(Const.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
if (oauth != -1) {
  int start = oath + Const.OATH_TOKEN_SECRET.length(); // or
  //int start = content.indexOf('=', oath) + 1;
  int end = content.indexOf('&', start);
  String tokenSecret = end == -1 ? content.substring(start) : content.substring(start, end);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for showing me how this can be done!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Map<String, String> buildQueryMap(String query)  
{  
  String[] params = query.split("&");  
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
  for (String param : params)  
  {
    String[] pair = param.split("=");
    String name = pair[0];  
    String value = pair[1];  
    map.put(name, value);  
  }  
  return map;  
}

// in your code
Map<String, String> queryMap = buildQueryMap("a=1&b=2&c=3....");
String tokenSecret = queryMap.get(Const.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
```

Comment: +1 this is the most robust, though a malformed input string could give null pointer or array index exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Using [String.split](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) gives a much cleaner solution.

```
static String getValue(String key, String content) {
  String[] tokens = content.split("[=&]");
  for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length - 1; ++i) {
    if(tokens[i].equals(key)) {
      return tokens[i+1];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

---

Click [here](http://ideone.com/GWqgKGeV) for a test drive! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A much better solution is using the [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and corresponding [Matcher](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class.

By using a capturing group you can check and "cut out" the the appropriate substring in one step.